# Where can I find the file to set the distance for the urg_node?

Tags: ros

I would like to set the distance at which urg_node is to be detected.

I changed lines 88 and 89 of the launch file, but the detection distance did not change

```
88  param name="range_min" type="double" value="0.01"

89  param name="range_max" type="double" value="50.0"
```

Source code in https://github.com/vstoneofficial/mecanumrover_samples

in mecanumrover_samples/launch/gmapping.launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this exact lidar but in urg_node documentation (http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node) there's no mention of parameters for min max detection range and I didn't find any implementation of it in the [source code](https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/blob/8e998246f9c657f722cf18c3f14b8fea73ed0637/src/urg_node_driver.cpp#L252). So it's not possible to do that directly without modifying source code of urg_node_driver.cpp. But there is a way

ROS way to do it would be to **pass lidar data through filter node and use the filtered output**. To do so can use [LaserScanRangeFilter filter config](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters#LaserScanRangeFilter) for laser_filters package:

And if you use filters you'll need to remap http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap some topic names to have correct data flow lidar->filter->gmapping/etc

PS lines 88 89 that you edited are meant for ydlidar_ros_driver I assume you're are not using ydlidar so that's not what you want